# How to get insert mode map to work regardless of completion popup?

Tags: key-bindings, ins-completion

I have an insert mode mapping which calls a function to select some text and leave vim in select mode.

```
inoremap <silent> <C-J> <C-\><C-O>:call MyFunction()<CR>
```

This works in regular insert mode; and it works when the insert-mode completion popup window is visible and I haven't pressed ctrl-p or ctrl-n.

It doesn't work when the insert-mode completion popup window is visible and I have pressed ctrl-p or ctrl-n.  In this case:

- the cursor moves to the expected location;
- the literal text `:call MyFunction()` with a newline is inserted in place of the text I wanted to be selected;
- vim remains in insert mode instead of switching to select mode.

I believe this is because the `C-\` at the start of the RHS is not part of the current completion option, so it has the effect of accepting the completion, which triggers `CompleteDone`, which executes `MyFunction()` (I listen for the `CompleteDone` event and in my listener call `MyFunction()`), and then the rest of the RHS is taken literally.

`completeopt` is `menuone,noinsert`.  `MyFunction()`looks like:

```
function! MyFunction()
  ...
  stopinsert
  call setpos("'<", ...)
  call setpos("'>", ...)
  execute "normal! gv\<C-G>"
endfunction
```

I tried this variation instead:

```
inoremap <silent> <C-J> <C-R>=pumvisible() ? '<C-Y>' : MyFunction()<CR>
```

This works when the completion window is open, both when I have and haven't pressed ctrl-p / ctrl-n; but it doesn't work in regular insert mode (it moves the cursor to the start of the line and switches to normal mode – I suspect because `MyFunction()` doesn't have an explicit `return`, and so implicitly returns `0`, which takes the cursor to the start of the line).

How can I get the mapping to work all the time?

Comment: Does `:h CTRL-\_CTRL-N` do what you want?

Comment: It puts me into normal mode which isn't quite what I want.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, yes, but then you are always considered to be in normal mode, from which you can call your function, regardless of what mode you have been in before, right?

Comment: True, but I can't seem to get it to work.  What exact map did you have in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your map:

**mistake 1**

[:h quote=](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#quote%3D) is expression register, it requires an expression. `MyFunction()` is a function, when it's used in an expression, it's result is returned, not itself. [:h :return](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3Areturn) says that if your function doesn't have an explicit `:return`, it returns 0. 0 is a normal mode command that move your cursor to column 1.  To fix that:

```
..... <c-r>= ...... : "\<lt>c-\>\<lt>c-o>:call MyFunction\<lt>cr>"<cr>
```

I will explain `"\<lt>cr>"` shortly.

**mistake 2**

Definition of map without `<expr>` is:

```
                        Map the key sequence {lhs} to {rhs} for the modes
                        where the map command applies.
```

It's **key sequence**, it works like you are typing it. The `<cr>` in the end is right because you want to press carriage return in the end of the `<c-r>=`. `<c-y>` here works by accident, because when you press `<c-y>` in command line, it inserts a literal `<c-y>`, but you can't rely on that, try `<cr>`, `<esc>`, they won't insert literal code for you.

Now let's come back to the ugly `"\<lt>cr>"`. Our goal is to return a literal `<cr>` after `MyFunction`, literal `<cr>` is `"\<cr>"` (check [:h string](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#string) ), in order to stop `map` command from interpreting `<cr>` as special keycode, we replace `<` with it's special keycode `<lt>`. The same rules applys to `<c-\>` and `<c-o>`.

**common way**

You should use `<expr>` instead of `<c-r>` unless there are special reasons ( eg: [:h complete()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#complete%28%29) ), because `<expr>` think that `{rhs}` is result of an `expression`, what ever you provided in your `<map>` is an expression, you don't need to worry about your second mistake inside an expression. I hope i have made my self clear. (my English is poor ~~)

```
inoremap <expr> <c-j> pumvisible() ? '<c-y>' : '<C-\><C-O>:call MyFunction()<CR>'
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  That all makes perfect sense and was very well explained (your English is excellent).  And it even works ;)